# What Return Value is expected in this Swift function?

Tags: swift

I am new to the Swift programming so have a question on the return value.

Suppose I have this code block:

```
@IBAction func verifyItemPressed() {
    if pinTextField.text?.isEmpty ?? true {
        UIAlertController.showAlertWith(title: "Test", message: "Empty entry!!")
        return
    }
```

In this case, what return value I can expect here. Since, what I know is that it should return either 0 or 1 and true or false (if I have defined bool).

Comment: `if pinTextField.text?.isEmpty ?? true` is wrong. should be `?? false` or a better syntax would be `== true`.  Note that the set field set property default value is an empty string, therefore it will never return nil so you can safely force unwrap the set property `if pinTextField.text!.isEmpty` or use `UIKeyInput` hasted property which is available for both `UITextField` and `UITextView`. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyinput

Comment: `if !pinTextField.hasText { ...`

Comment: @LeoDabus Unwrapping optionals as soon as possible is usually the easiest to read `(pinTextField.text ?? "").isEmpty`. I don't see why `pinTextField.text?.isEmpty ?? true` should be incorrect.

Comment: @LeoDabus The `?? true` is correct. That will treat nil text the same as empty text. Of course `UITextField text` will never be `nil` so in the end it doesn't matter.

Comment: @rmaddy in this case it doesn't matter but in general optional bool when the object is nil you usually treat the conditional as false. `== true` or `== false` IMO is the way to go when dealing with `Bool?` types. `(pinTextField.text ?? "")` is pointless

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes, everything else in your first comment is fine except the part suggesting the `?? true` is wrong and should be `?? false`.

Comment: @LeoDabus Why would you do that? I think that the treatment of `nil` depends on the context and there is no "in general".

Comment: I don't agree with the use of the nil coalescing at all when dealing with optional Bool. Just personal preference. I don't see a situation where I would need to use it.

Comment: I'm confused. When does **any** `@IBAction` on what appears to be a `UIButton` have a return. In fact, in your example it doesn't. What happens when your remove that line? (I'm actually suprprised your code builds without an error. But I could be wrong....)

Comment: return there just mean early exit. It just returns void

Comment: @Leo_Dabus, but the question clearly states that it's asking what type! Either the code is incomplete or the question isn't.

Comment: @dfd The code in the question is simply being shown without the rest of the function. Note there is no closing brace. The `return` here appears to be a "leave now, don't finish" kind of return.

Comment: Got it. Very misleading question - and code.

Comment: @user2670674 You should both the whole method in your question. The partial method is leading to some confusion about what you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

There is no return value to expect. The function has no return value. The empty `return` simply means "leave the function now, don't do anything else".

In Swift there are three ways to indicate that a function has no return value:

```
func foo1() -> Void {
    return
}

func foo2() -> () {
    return
}

func foo3() {
    return
}
```

The last is the most common since it is the shortest.

A function with no return value doesn't need a call to `return` at all. If it does, it is typically done to leave the function early due to some condition or error as in the code in your question.